# How to download an image if i have the image url using requests library in python?

Tags: python-requests, shutil

```
import shutil
import requests

url = 'http://example.com/img.png'
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('img.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)
del response
```

I have tried Using the above code that i found on stackoverflow, but could not get it to work.
I have a few doubts as to where will the image be saved and what exactly is the parmeter "out_file".

All help is very much appriciated !
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error you're getting?

I tested this out, and it saved the image in the same directory as the python script, which was on my Desktop.

If you want to save it somewhere specific, you can specify the full path. For example:`with open('C:\Temp\img.png', 'wb') as out_file:
  shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file)`

`out_file` is basically your file, and it supports operations such as write, close, etc. For more info see: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files.